# Process not running from script under cron

Tags: linux, bash, cron

My cron plan is:

```
* * * * *    /home/sa-mp/samp03/fix.sh
```

My script is:

```
#!/bin/bash
if ! pgrep samp03svr; then
  /home/sa-mp/samp03/samp03svr &
  echo "$(date): Process start" >> /home/sa-mp/samp03/restart_log.txt
fi
```

On manually calling the script, it's works fine, but when cron call that script the process "samp03svr" not running.

The script's and process's permissions are 755.

The line from var/log/cron.log:

```
/USR/SBIN/CRON[3662]: (root) CMD (/home/sa-mp/samp03/fix.sh)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
* * * * *    /home/sa-mp/samp03/fix.sh >  /home/sa-mp/samp03/fix.sh.out
```

Please let us know what is samp03svr.

Comment: This only create an empty fix.sh.out file. samp03svr is gaming server.